# Java Persistence API (JPA): additional constraints on a relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA, can I additionally constrain `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` to produce something  equivalent to:

```
select * from other_table a where a.fk_id = {id} and arbitrary other predicates
```

?

Or in other words, I can get all the Employee's Phones with this:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name="EMP_ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phones;
  ...
}
```

But what if I want three lists:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name="EMP_ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phonesInAreaCode212;  // only NYC phone numbers

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phonesInAreaCode202;  // only DC phone numbers

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phonesInOtherAreaCodes; // areaCode not in ('212', '202')
  ...
}
```

I know I could do this by using views, and I could probably do it with single table inheritance and a discriminator column, but is there a way to do this for any arbitrary where clause predicate (including compound predicates)?

Comment: There is a way of doing this for hibernate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27945738/1073063, but I don't think there is a JPA generic way for this.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting for lazy fetch, which it is probably doing anyway, e.g.,

`@OneToMany(Fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`

and then doing a fetch on only the lists you want, like so:

`employee.getPhonesInAreaCode212.size();`