# JPA @JoinTable with extra join conditions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

I have spent couple of hours searching around and did not found anything similar to my case.

Let's assume following many-to-many data model:

```
Contract (any business entity)
- contract_id
- other fields

Party (another business entity)
- party_id
- other fields

Contract_Party (relations between first two 
with additional role indicator, e.g. owner, signer, seller, etc)
- contract_id
- party_id
- role
```

Now let's assume I want to map **all** contracts related to party (uni-directional). It can be done using following annotations in `Party` entity class:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="Contract_Party", 
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="party_id", referencedColumnName="party_id")},
  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="contract_id", referencedColumnName="contract_id")}
}
private List<Contract> contracts;
```

That is fine.

But what I'm looking for is how to map contracts with **particular role**?

```
@OneToMany
@??? ( "ROLE = 'SIGNER' ")
private List<Contract> signedContracts;
```

Technically I'm looking for a way to add **extra condition** into JOIN statement.

So far found following ideas in similar topics:

- map join table as separate entity, and perform filtering by role using custom queries;
- Hibernate has @JoinFormula annotation, but no way to apply it inside @JoinTable;
- Hibernate also has @Where annotation, but it adds condition for Contract table not for join table;
- use @MapKeyColumn and return Map instead of List, but I can have multiple contracts per one role;
- create a view on DB side (this one works indeed :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use @WhereJoinTable annotation. It applies to the association table

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="Contract_Party", 
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="party_id",referencedColumnName="party_id")},
  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="contract_id", referencedColumnName="contract_id")}
}
@WhereJoinTable  ( "ROLE = 'SIGNER' ")
private List<Contract> contracts;
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.
I also had this question, but from the point of view of such:  How do I call all the Parties, so that have a list of contracts corresponding to a role='signer' ?  Can I use a query to do this ?  JPA query that is?

Comment: related: `@JoinFormula`

Comment: @WhereJoinTable(clause = "ROLE ='SIGNER'")

Answer (score 4):

You must use:

```
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "ROLE ='SIGNER'")
```