# JPA ManyToMany relationship with additional filter

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities: Citizen and Address.

Citizen can have two types of Address - real and registration. And each one is a List.

So, there are two fields in my Citizen entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "TBCITIZEN_REG_ADDRESS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CITIZEN_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID"))
private List<Address> registrationAddresses;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "TBCITIZEN_REAL_ADDRESS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CITIZEN_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID"))
private List<Address> realAddresses;
```

As you can see, i use two tables in DB to map a relationship between entities. And if another type will be added, i should add a new table.

I want to map relationship using something like this in DB:

```
CITIZEN_ID  |   ADDRESS_ID  | TYPE
1           |   1           | REAL
1           |   2           | REAL
1           |   1           | REG
2           |   3           | REAL
```

Is there a way to use it for map ManyToMany with JPA?

UPD

I know that there is [@WhereJoinTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945738/jpa-jointable-with-extra-join-conditions) Hibernate annotation. But i'm using EclipseLink and it would be great to handle it with pure JPA

Comment: I resolve similar problem by generating third Entity f.e. pseudocode `class CitizenAddresLink { @Column citizen; @Column addres; @EnumColumn  kind }` No debugging, no hard intellectual work. One table for Addres class, Your two tables for one relation seems strange (maybe I don't understand)

Comment: Time for edition is gone, correction: one table for relation

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try to implement it.